# How to install ubuntu on new preloaded dos system?

Tags: installation, dell, inspiron

Recently I bought new laptop without operating system in it.It has only freeloaded DOS that's it.
Now I made a boot-able USB drive with Ubuntu in it.It went to fourth step properly with out any issue,but the problem is after that its not detecting the Internet connection even though I already connected using wired connection.

Give me any suggestions to load Ubuntu on my new laptop.

Model:Dell Inspiron 15,i3 3251

Comment: Please edit your question to include make and model of your laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should install Ubuntu first without connecting to the internet, what I mean to say is skip the ***Download updates while installing*** and ***Install third-party software***. Once the installation is complete, reboot and then update/upgrade your system, install the applications/software that you need.

After you log-in to the Ubuntu Desktop, connect your ethernet cable. If you're still unable to connect to the internet, start troubleshoot.

When you're connected to the internet, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following to update and upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```